# Autoejecutable en windows

Tags: r

Quiero hacer un fichero en R autoejecutable.

Tengo algunos hechos en linux y me iba bien, pero ahora tengo que hacerlos en windows y no lo consigo.

En la siguiente ruta tengo una carpeta llamada "prueba"

```
C:\Users\Desktop\prueba
```

Dentro de esa carpeta tengo este script llamado "script.R" que crea un df y lo guarda como csv.

```
data1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 1:5)
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/prueba")
write.csv2(data1, "data1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Ejecuto el script desde Rstudio y efectivamente me guarda un csv en la carpeta "prueba".

Quiero hacerlo autoejecutable desde windows 11.

Para ello busco donde está instalado R.

Si pongo esta ruta `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe` en el navegador de windows me abre R.

Entonces creo un fichero.txt en el escritorio con el siguiente texto:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla
--slave C:\Users\Desktop\prueba\script.R
quit
```

Guardo el txt como "prueba.bat"

Doble click en el fichero "prueba.bat".
Se me abre la pantalla negra del sistema un segundo, se cierra , y no pasa nada. No me crea el csv.

Comment: Lo probé en un Win10 y funcionó perfectamente, prueba agregar el comando PAUSE antes de salir del BAT para ver si la ejecución muestra algo por pantalla, también  revisa si te generó un archivo `.out`, editalo con el notepad, para ver como fue la ejecución.

Comment: Con el PAUSE, me dice que "--slave" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. Si lo quito me abre script.R en el Rstudio.

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedo reproducir el problema, a mi me funciona bien, solo puedo sugerirte algunas pruebas 1) Invoca el ejecutable de R sin parámetros 2) Revisa el archivo  `Prueba.Rout ` o como se llame en tu caso, ahí tienes el resultado real de la ejecución 3) Prueba usar `Rscript.exe` en vez de `R.exe`, siempre sin parámetros.

Comment: No me genera ningún *.out. Creo que el ordenador que estoy usando esta capado y no se puede ejecutar ningún exe sin permiso del administrador, lo mismo van por ahi los tiros.

Comment: Puede haber un tema de permisos de escritura en la carpeta, probaría lo mismo en otra carpeta y como última prueba, en vez de ejecutar el BAT iría a la carpeta y desde una terminal, ejecutaría directamente el comando, simplemente para ver si se puede ver algún mensaje. Suerte.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe" --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\Desktop\prueba\script.R"` en una sola línea.

También puede usar Rscript.exe en lugar de R.exe

CMD BATCH es un comando de cron en linux.

Comment: Gracias. Funcionó quitando CMD BATCH, poniéndolo todo en una sola línea y con Rscript.exe